# Use of WP Plugin 'Digits' for Activation/Authentication link for new registrants on CellPhone instead of Email

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I am developing a membership website.
In one of your answers on page 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49203053/register-woocommerce-by-phone-number-instead-email' about 'Digits' plugin regarding solution for OTP and SMS structure in WordPress websites, I tried to find 'Digits' plugin but in vain.
I want new Registrants through their Mobile phone instead of their Email address.
Please note that I am a hobbiest only.
Thank you for your time.
Saeed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.